# Android Status Bar Icon Only

Tags: android, notifications

I've created many different types of android status bar notifications.  I'm wondering if there is a way to show a status bar icon but not have any item show up in the list when they pull down the menu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry -- a `Notification` always has an entry in the drawer. Otherwise, the user cannot get rid of the `Notification` (directly or by determining what the `Notification` is tied to, so they can take other steps to get rid of it, up to and including uninstalling the app).